# How to efficiently compute the commutator $[\hat{r},\nabla^2]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, differentiation, commutator

Given a system with Hamiltonian $ \hat{H} = \frac {\hat{p} ^2}{2m} + \hat{V}(r)$ in a certain state $|\psi \rangle$, I want to find if $\langle r \rangle$ varies with time.

From

$$ i \hbar\frac {d \langle r \rangle} {dt} = \langle [\hat{r},\hat{H}]  \rangle$$

Since $[\hat{r}, \hat{V}(r)] = 0$, we have

$$[\hat{r},\hat{H}] = -\frac {\hbar ^2}{2m}[\hat{r},\nabla^2]$$

- What is the **most efficient** way to compute $[\hat{r},\nabla^2]$ ?

*My approach*:

Write $\nabla ^2$ in spherical coordinates, and since $\hat{r}$ commutes with the angular part what remains is (omitting the hats)

$$ \left[r, \frac {1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)\right]$$

to be computed with the help of a test function.

Comment: The Laplacian is **not** the momentum operator: it is the *representation* of the momentum operator onto the position basis (as such your initial equation makes no sense, on the left hand side you have an operator, on the right hand side you have a representation).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so you're looking for the commutator 
$$\left[r,\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^2\partial_r\right]$$
Where I let $\partial/\partial r=\partial_r$.
Expanding, you get
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{r}\partial_r r^2\partial_r  - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^2\partial_rr \\ &= \frac{1}{r}\partial_r r^2\partial_r - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^3\partial_r-\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^2 
\\&=\frac{1}{r}\partial_r r^2\partial_r - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^3\partial_r-\partial_r - \frac{2}{r}
\\&=\frac{1}{r}\left(r^2\partial^2_r+2r\partial_r \right)-\frac{1}{r^2}\left( r^3\partial^2_r+3r^2\partial_r\right)-\partial_r-\frac{2}{r} \\
&=r\partial^2_r+2\partial_r-r\partial^2_r-3\partial_r-\partial_r-\frac{2}{r} \\
&=-2\left(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r}\right)
\end{align}
So your equation simplifies to
$$m\frac{d\langle r \rangle}{dt}=-i\hbar\nabla-\frac{i\hbar}{r} $$
Or
$$m\frac{d\langle r \rangle}{dt}=\hat{p}-\frac{i\hbar}{r}$$

Comment: This seems correct, however it is the same approach I propose in the question. I am interested in faster ways to do it if there are any. Also watch out for that third entry in the commutator!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't you were looking for another approach; you may want to make that more clear in your question. Thank you for pointing that out! I just edited it.